# How do I expose Oracle connection pool statistics over JMX?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, jmx

I am using an Oracle connection pool by using the following Spring configuration for my datasource:

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="URL" value="myUrl" />
    <property name="user" value="myUserName" />
    <property name="password" value="myPassword" />
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="InitialLimit">5</prop>
            <prop key="MinLimit">5</prop>
            <prop key="MaxLimit">30</prop>
            <prop key="MaxStatementsLimit">20</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I would like to expose the statistics of this pool via JMX so that I can monitor the pool to see how many connections are in the pool, how many are busy, etc.

I am connecting to an Oracle 10g server with the oracle 11.2.0.3.0 jdbc driver.

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi. Have you any news on this old subject? I've the same one : beans are created with XML files on Karaf but I've not found a JMX access to get the number of active connections. Thanks.

Comment: @elo Sorry it's been a long time since I used Spring with XML or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

[**MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jmx/export/assembler/MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler.html)

> ```
> public class MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler
> ```
>
> Subclass of `AbstractReflectiveMBeanInfoAssembler` that allows to
>   specify method names to be exposed as MBean operations and attributes.
>   JavaBean getters and setters will automatically be exposed as JMX
>   attributes.
>
> You can supply an array of method names via the `managedMethods`
>   property. If you have multiple beans and you wish each bean to use a
>   different set of method names, then you can map bean keys (that is the
>   name used to pass the bean to the `MBeanExporter`) to a list of method
>   names using the `methodMappings` property.
>
> If you specify values for both `methodMappings` and `managedMethods`,
>   Spring will attempt to find method names in the mappings first. If no
>   method names for the bean are found, it will use the method names
>   defined by `managedMethods`.

For example -

```
...
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="mbeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
   <property name="assembler">
      <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler">         
         <property name="managedMethods">
         <list>
            <value>getNumActive</value>
            <value>getMaxActive</value>
            <value>getNumIdle</value>
            <value>getMaxIdle</value>
            <value>getMaxWait</value>
            <value>getInitialSize</value>
         </list>
         </property>         
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="beans">
       <map>                   
          <entry key="dataSource:name=DataSource" value-ref="dataSource"/>    
       </map>
    </property>

    <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />

</bean>
```

Comment: That worked to expose the mbean, but it did not expose any attributes. I think this is because http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html does not have any of those methods, eg. getNumActive etc...

Answer (score 0):

For **Enabling JMX in Hibernate, EhCache, Quartz, DBCP and Spring**
Kindly refer the http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/12/enabling-jmx-in-hibernate-ehcache-qurtz.html